# Unable to update properties in mongoose object using nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Somehow I'm unable to update properties of a mongoose object I fetch from a MongoDB. I'm trying to follow this pattern: [Mongoose Docs: Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-save)

This is my code:

```js
// note: getInstances just returns model.find()
let instances: InstanceDocument[] = await this.instanceService.getInstances();
instances.forEach(async (instance, index) => {
    console.log(instance);
    let deviceCount = await this.instanceService.getDeviceCount(instance._id);
    let elementCount = await this.instanceService.getElementCount(instance._id)
    instance.deviceCount = deviceCount;
    instance.elementCount = elementCount;
    await instance.save();
    console.log(deviceCount, elementCount, instance);
})
```

The `console.log` prints the correct values for `deviceCount` and `elementCount`, but the instance object remains unmodified. It still has the unupdated values it has in the database.

Note: this is not a duplicate entry of [Unable to add properties to js object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554350/unable-to-add-properties-to-js-object), as I'm not trying to create a new object and give it properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things :

1. You can't use `await` inside an array method like `forEach` or `map`. It [doesn't work](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/ExWXjKa) (doesn't await). Use a `for` loop instead.
2. Mongoose has this weird requirement that you must explicitely tell it that a nested key has been modified in order to save it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054552/mongoose-not-saving-nested-object)

```
let instances: InstanceDocument[] = await this.instanceService.getInstances();

for(let instance of instances) {
    console.log(instance);
    instance.deviceCount = await this.instanceService.getDeviceCount(instance._id);
    instance.elementCount = await this.instanceService.getElementCount(instance._id);

    instance.markModified("deviceCount"); // this
    instance.markModified("elementCount"); // and this

    await instance.save();
    console.log(deviceCount, elementCount, instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above works. I made a mistake in defining the objects schema. I missed @Prop() decorator for the properties I added. This code works:

```js
let instances: InstanceDocument[] = await this.instanceService.getInstances();
let fetchingDone = new Subject();
fetchingDone.subscribe(instances => res.json(instances))

instances.forEach(async (instance, index) => {
  instance.deviceCount = await this.instanceService.getDeviceCount(instance._id);
  instance.elementCount = await this.instanceService.getElementCount(instance._id);
  await instance.save();
  if (index+1 === instances.length) fetchingDone.next(instances);
})
```